# Iam having a problem with adding fields in a hive model in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-hive

When I tried to add a new field(intWrkTime)
and I had generated a new adapter, I had this problem although I had initialized it in all my usages.

The error:

> Unhandled Exception: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'int' in type cast

```
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';
part 'emp_model.g.dart';

@HiveType(typeId: 0)
class EmployeeModel extends HiveObject
{
  @HiveField(0)
  late String empName;

  @HiveField(2)
  late int idWrkTime;

  EmployeeModel({
    required this.empName,
    required this.idWrkTime,
  });
}
```

Comment: That error is because the `idWrkTime` is `null` when you try to use it. You have to ensure that the variable has a value before using it. You can also assign a default value to that variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do like this

```
    @HiveType(typeId: 0)
class TaskEntitiy extends HiveObject {
  int id = -1;
  @HiveField(0)
  String name = '';
  @HiveField(1)
  bool isCompleted = false;
 
}
```

dont put late before fields and give them default amount

> Blockquote